# Libraries after upgrade R?

Tags: r

I just upgrade R to 3.1. I am wondering how to install all the packages I have installed in the previous version. I have 126 packages under R 3.0:

```
> length(list.files("/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library"))
[1] 126
```

How could I transfer these packages under the new R 3.1, is it okay to copy the old library just to the new library path?

Comment: Yes. Copy, then `update.packages()` and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just copy the old library to the new library path. Then update your packages using the following code:

```
update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)
```